# Display new.html.erb as a partial in index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to display the new.html.erb `form_for` div in index.html.erb?

I'd like to be able to add a new entry without leaving the homepage.  Maybe a partial?

Answer (score 0):

You can't render part of the template, only whole templete.

If you have a part that same for several templates, than put it to the partial and render partial as part of the template.

This is very simple example:

_partial.rb:

```
<%= form_for ... %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb:

```
render 'partial'
```

index.html.erb:

```
render 'partial'
```

More about partials and rendering you can read in [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by creating a @article = Article.create in the index module of the controller.  Works like a charm.  No partials needed.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me.

In the links_controller.rb I added the @link to the index controller

```
def index
 @links = Link.all
 @link = Link.new
end
```

In the index.html.erb I added only the partial

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Ended up with the screen of this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Yes partial would be better in that case. You can have a partial for that "_form.html.erb".
In that partial just put the `form_for` content. Let you have a Blog model and in the index you are showing the blog lists.

```
def index
 @blog = Blog.new
 #your rest code goes here
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<YOUR HTML CONTENT>
<%= render "/blogs/form" %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@blog) do |f| %>
   Your code for the form
 <%= end %>
```

If you want to keep the new action will show only the form, then you need to change the action and new.html.erb

```
def new
  @blog = Blog.new
end
```

In new.html.erb

```
<%= render '/blogs/form' %>
```

Comment: It's not a good way to call one action from another. Actually, it's really bad. Extract the same part to the method and call extracted method not the action method.

Comment: I just experimented in that way, got succeeded. Yes we can have it by using two partials. +1 for you dude.. I am going to modify that :)